# get foreach item in foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have table called **paper_type** and another called **paper_group** now each paper type is put under a paper group. This is my table structure

**paper_group:**
paper_group_id,name.

**paper_type:**
paper_type_id,paper_group_id,name.

I am trying to load paper type into a multiselect, but I want it to be grouped by paper_group_id and the paper_group name to show as the optgroup value. I know I can do a foreach in a foreach to achieve this but I don't know if this is an ideal way to get things done. Is there a better way I can achieve this result?

```
public function select_from_printtype(){
  $que = $this->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM print_type a
    JOIN print_type_group b ON a.print_type_group_id=b.print_type_group_id
    ORDER BY b.print_type_group_id DESC
  ");
  return $que;
}
```

**Select**

```
<select id="basic" multiple="multiple" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-live-search="true">
  <?php 
  $notarray = DataDB::getInstance()->select_from_printtype();
  foreach($notarray as $row):
    ?>
    <optgroup label="<?php echo $row['group'];?>">
      <option value="<?php echo $row['print_type_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
    </optgroup>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

what this code above does is that it repeats the group name instead of having all the types under one group

Comment: Have you tried using a join query so as the query returns the data already sorted. Running loops on big data sets can be expensive

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Do not do this in a loop. That is not how databases work. Please share some sample data and your desired results and we can help write a SQL statement to get exactly what you want.

Comment: It depends. You have to decide on your own structure. You can have two arrays, select them separately what you need. And do foreach in foreach. Or you can make one query with join, select what you need, order by paper group and do one foreach for data conversions to one 2d array. And two foreachs for output. At this point you could not go wrong much. Just do what you know, and later on you will fit solution to your needs

Comment: just edited my question to add my code and my join statement @JNevill

Comment: @nsikak Thanks for the code. That does help make your issue more clear. Now that I see it, it does seem like this is more of a PHP ("Whats the best way to get this multiselect filled with this DB resultset") and less of a MySQL ("How can I select this data more efficiently"). Your results set is correct for your needs, unless there are any MySQL kung fu folks here that could get a JSON output where your `type_id` and `name` is aggregated in a JSON array under each of your distinct `group` values.